Option Market Making fitting the vol surface
As an option Market Maker why do you need an auto-fitter for the vol surface, and why using the mid in the wings is not a good pratice?
My guess would be that you need to fit the vol surface to be able to quote? So for example you observe that the implied vol of call with strike $K$ is $\sigma$ and the implied vol with strike $K+1$ is $\sigma_1$. Why would need to interpolate the vol surface between $\sigma$ and $\sigma_1$ for example?
If you want to quote for the call with strike $K$ you don't need to know what is the implied vol for the strike $K+ \epsilon$ right?
You are probably just going to take the implied vol $\sigma$ and skew it by a certain amount and that's it. That's why I don't really get why you need to fit the vol surface when being an option MM and also apparently, it's harder in the wings but I don't know why. If someone has any ideas that would really help my understanding.


why do you need an auto-fitter for the vol surface[?]

I don't understand your terminology. Do you mean an automated fitting process when you use the term "auto-fitter", or are you suggesting use of an auto-encoder for representing the volatility surface. An auto-encoder approach would be cool, but likely a bit "heavy" for a latency sensitive market making.
Fitting a smooth surface offers a noise reduced estimate of a volatility.

Why would [you] need to interpolate the vol surface[?]


Volatility is not associated with strike as much as it is a associated with moneyness. Moneyness changes when the underlying changes. A smooth surface offers guidance after underlying price movement.
Its a noise reduction method.


it's harder in the wings

Some issues you must endure in the "wings" include wider bid-ask spreads (observation noise) and lower sensitivity to volatility (lower vega), which makes a market descriptor fixated on volatility problematic.
